# Attach photo to Activity through Google + Domains API

Tags: google-plus

Im trying to post an activity with an image to a google+ domain with the new google + domains API

Posting an activity is working fine but when i try to attach a photo to it, i receive a 500 error with null description.

This is the code:

```
String msg = "Activity with photo";

// Create a list of ACL entries
PlusAclentryResource resource = new PlusAclentryResource();
resource.setType("domain"); // Share to domain

List<PlusAclentryResource> aclEntries = new ArrayList<PlusAclentryResource>();
aclEntries.add(resource);

Acl acl = new Acl();
acl.setItems(aclEntries);
acl.setDomainRestricted(true);  // Required, this does the domain restriction

// Create a new activity object
Activity activity = new Activity()
    .setObject(new Activity.PlusObject().setOriginalContent(msg))
    .setAccess(acl);

// Attach the link
Activity.PlusObject.Attachments attachment = new Activity.PlusObject.Attachments();
attachment.setObjectType("photo");
attachment.setUrl( "http://c299813.r13.cf1.rackcdn.com/MuseeduLouvre_1335428699_org.jpg" );
attachment.setId( randomId ); //if not specified, google returns an error with "you must specify the photo id"

List<Activity.PlusObject.Attachments> attachments = new ArrayList();
attachments.add(attachment);    // You can also add multiple attachments to the post
activity.getObject().setAttachments(attachments);

activity = plus.activities().insert("me", activity).execute();
```

When the code calls the execute, i receive this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
}
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
```

The same code but with the attachemnt lines commented works fine. Has someone managed to create an activity with an image? any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly attaching a photo via URL isn't possible. The process works slightly differently, as described here: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/attaching-media

If you don't have the actual binary data of the photo you will first have to "download" the photo. Then you can upload the actual photo data via the `media().insert` method, which will give you the Photo Id which you can then use in `attachment.setId()`.
`setUrl` isn't necessary in this case.

If you want to attach a photo as URL, this could also be handled like an `article` attachment (same as if you would just copy/paste the URL into a Google+ post). In that case you would use `attachment.setObjectType("article")` and only set the Url. The id isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: i want to send the photo as URL. I changed the "photo" by "article" and start working. Thanx for the tip!